# How can I update a virtual machine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I've to share a virtual machine that is an updated version (new things are installed in it) with respect to the one already installed. I want to ask, how can other people take the folder of new VM and update the old one already present on VirtualBox?

Comment: What I understand is this: You want to make two different VMs similar (wrt the packages installed and their settings). Why don't you just copy the updated one over the old one and change its host name (and any host related things, like static IP addresses etc.)?

Comment: Yea, you are right